# What is the neo4j-rest-graphdb version which supports neo4j-community-2.3.0-M02

Tags: java, neo4j

What is the neo4j-rest-graphdb version which supports neo4j-community-2.3.0-M02 version?
I'm already checked 2.0.0-M06,2.0.0 and 2.0.1 versions but all gives following exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading as JSON ''
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.readJson(JsonHelper.java:57)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.jsonToSingleValue(JsonHelper.java:62)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult.toEntity(RequestResult.java:114)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult.toMap(RequestResult.java:120)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.batch.CypherResult.<init>(CypherResult.java:43)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:554)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:574)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.query(RestAPIFacade.java:235)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.query.RestCypherQueryEngine.query(RestCypherQueryEngine.java:50)
```

I have no control on db versions so I can't upgrade or downgrade neo4j db version. 
 I'm already spent 2-3 days on this problem so anyone knows a solution for this please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting @MichaelHunger ([Best solution for multiple queries in a limited time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29622464/best-solution-for-multiple-queries-in-a-limited-time)):

> I would not recommend RestGraphDatabase and friends, because it is
>   slow and outdated.

I think there's no good neo4j-rest-graphdb version for Neo4j 2.3 since it's no longer maintained so you may have to switch to another connector ([jdbc-neo4](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc)j is maintained)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to remove authentication in the new version of Neo4J.

Follow these steps :

> **Go to options** 
>   -> click Edit button in Server Configuration 
>   -> set dbms.security.auth_enabled=false (do not comment on this, because default values still true)